# Alignment div under another div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner on this side of web development and I don't understand a thing, more precisely on the alignment side. 
In my project I have the features area and when I add it, it adds me further, and I want it down, under that search bar and the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU5nT.png

Here is my code:

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>Baza de date</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Acasa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Cautare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Adaugare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hospital-alt"></i>Centre</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
      <form>
        <div class="inner-form">
          <div class="input-field first-wrap">
            <div class="input-select">
              <select data-trigger="" name="choices-single-defaul">
                <option placeholder="">Grupe de sange</option>
                <option>0</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>AB</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Cantitatea de sange" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-field third-wrap">
            <button class="btn-search" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container py-5 my-5 z-depth-1">
      <section class="p-md-3 mx-md-5 text-lg-left">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-center mb-5 pb-3">Features</h2>
        <div class="row text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-lg-0 mb-5">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x indigo-text mb-4"></i>
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-4">Feature 1</h4>
            <p class="text-muted px-2 mb-lg-0">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/extention/choices.js"></script>
    <script>
      const choices = new Choices('[data-trigger]',
      {
        searchEnabled: false,
        itemSelectText: '',
      });

    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, use bootstrap

Comment: Can you share CSS please?

Comment: @prathameshk73 here: https://pastebin.com/iPcJCc5U

Answer (score 0):

You must add the image in the html and then apply those properties float:left; width:100%; to the layer that wrap the searcher and the image.

If you apply as background the image in the CSS you can't do that.

Comment: You still have the image as background in the CSS properties so first of all you must add the image in the HTML as <img> label.